# WCF net.tcp binding 808:* what does this mean?

Tags: wcf

I am trying to connect to a WCF service someone set up and i'm having trouble, 
I have no idea what 808:* means in the "Binding Information" for net.tcp site bindings.

thanks

this is how the bindings are configured in IIS 7  (navigate to IIS, right click on the application hosting the service, click 'edit bindings'). there are two entries:

type: http, port: 8000, ip address: *, binding information: (empty)

type: net.tcp, port: (empty), ip address: (empty), binding information: 808:*

Comment: Are you getting some error like this? Can you elaborate? Also include the exact endpoint, you wish to connect to.

Comment: here's an example of someone saying to set net.tcp up this way: http://expertise4you.blogspot.com/2008_08_01_archive.html

Comment: I got exactly the same question, thanks for raising this up.

Answer (score 7):

I understand this is an old post but this might help someone that comes back looking for an answer similar to this:

`808` is your port number you listen on 
`*` is a wild card for host name which means it will handle any requests coming in on port 808 with any host name.

Comment: So can I use a concrete IP instead of a host name?

Comment: Is the asterisk (`*`) really a wildcard *for the host name*? AFAIK TCP/IP network packets do not contain any host name information, but only IP addresses. (This is unlike HTTP requests, which have the host name used in a request URL in the `Host:` header.) So how would IIS be able to determine the host name used for an incoming TCP request?

Comment: I assume 808:* is the same as \*:808:\*. The format is ip address:port:host for http/https protocols. Since net.tcp is listening on port 808 the 808 portion is definitely the port.